# Add Expires headers for files with query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching

I have added Expire Headers to my .htaccess:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

But gtmetrix says "There are 30 static components without a far-future expiration date."

I realized that all the files with query string are not included to be cached. For example:

```
history.js?ver=1.7.1
history.adapter.jquery.js?ver=1.7.1
jquery.form.min.js?ver=3.48.0-2013.12.28
respond.min.js?ver=3.8.1
```

How can I add caching for those files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik the query string is ignored by mod_expire

However you may have to include more types, e.g.

```
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
```

Also wildcards can help you

`ExpiresByType image/* "access plus 1 year"`